# How can I replace a plus sign in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I need to make a replace of a plus sign in a javascript string. there might be multiple occurrence of the plus sign so I did this up until now:

```
myString= myString.replace(/+/g, "");#
```

This is however breaking up my javascript and causing glitches. How do you escape a '+' sign in a regular expression?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
myString = myString.replace(/\+/g, "");
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to escape the `+` as its a meta char as follows:

```
myString= myString.replace(/\+/g, "");
```

Once escaped, `+` will be treated literally and not as a meta char.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this:

```
myString.replace(/[+]/g, '').
```

Answer (score 2):

you should escape your `+` sign, `\+`

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.replace(/\+/g, "");
```