# Discord text output alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Currently running a discord bot that reads from a file and posts to a channel the new data in the file. Would like to make the output a quote to ignore the ~~ that appear consistently that format into a strike out line.

```
Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');

const SECONDS = 20;
const FILENAME = 'file.txt';
const TOKEN = '';
const CHANNEL = '';
var lineCount = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split('\n').length;


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

setInterval(function() {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('file.txt').toString().split('\r\n');
    if(data.length > lineCount) { //new lines have been added
        data = data.slice(lineCount, data.length);
        lineCount += data.length;
        client.channels.get(CHANNEL).send(data);
    }
}, SECONDS*20);

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I replace a plus sign in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469207/how-can-i-replace-a-plus-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

prepend and append three backticks ``` to the message being sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace for this.

```
string = string.replace(/\~/g, "");
```