# Replace A word In A String

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to replace the word  _New+Delivery; in a string with comma ( ',')

sample input string : `XP_New+Delivery;HP_New+Delivery;LA_New;`

expected output  : `XP,HP,LA_New;`

But it is returning the same input as output, not replacing anything any idea?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(new RegExp('_New+Delivery;', 'gi'), ',');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">XP_New+Delivery;HP_New+Delivery;LA_New;</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: `+` has a special meaning in RegExp's you'll need to *escape* it , '\+` ... or inside that string you'll need `\\+` ... so `var res = str.replace(new RegExp('_New\\+Delivery;', 'gi'), ',');` or `var res = str.replace(/_New\+Delivery;/gi, ',');` for more succinct code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I replace a plus sign in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469207/how-can-i-replace-a-plus-sign-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var str = "XP_New+Delivery;HP_New+Delivery;LA_New;";
var res = str.replace(/(_New\+Delivery;)/g, ",");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be not perfect way but it will work.

```js
const sampleInput = "XP_New+Delivery;HP_New+Delivery;LA_New;";
const result = sampleInput.split('_New+Delivery;').join(',');

console.log(result)
```

For your problem use following code

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
  var res = str.split('_New+Delivery;').join(',');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">XP_New+Delivery;HP_New+Delivery;LA_New;</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign in regex means "Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed". To use plus sign as is you need to escape it with special `\`.

```
new RegExp('_New\+Delivery;', 'gi')
```

But in your example The backslash is being interpreted by the code that reads the string, rather than passed to the regular expression parser. You need to double escape the plus sign:

```
new RegExp('_New\\+Delivery;', 'gi')
```